# TPNGImage.LoadFromFile EPNGInvalidFileHeader

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-10-seattle

I was given a .png file which renders correctly in windows explorer but wouldn't load into my application. Whenever I tried to load the file it would throw a `EPNGInvalidFileHeader` exception, here's the simple loading code.

```
uses Vcl.Imaging.PngImage;

var
    image: TPngImage;
begin
    image := TPngImage.Create();
    try
        image.LoadFromFile('somefile');    
    finally
        image.Free();
    end;
end;
```

So looking at where the exception was being raised in `LoadFromFile` lead me to

```
const
    PngHeader: Array[0..7] of AnsiChar = (#137, #80, #78, #71, #13, #10, #26, #10);

procedure TPngImage.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream);

...

    {Reads the header}
    Stream.Read(Header[0], 8);

    {Test if the header matches}
    if Header <> PngHeader then
    begin
        RaiseError(EPNGInvalidFileHeader, EPNGInvalidFileHeaderText);
        Exit;
    end;

...
```

The header for the file I have is actually `[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70]` which is of course not a valid PNG file header. Opening the file in notepad reveals what appears to be adobe photoshop meta information with references to `Exif` and some XML

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0">
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" photoshop:DateCreated="2017-04-04T19:38:31"/>
    </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

So after all of that explanation my question is **how can I load this apparently valid png image.** Windows Explorer, Paint, Gimp, Windows Photos, all render the image but I can't load it in my delphi application.

[Here is the test file](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AqDiuipRF0yymhSDAff-Lq3WRBIm) (yes it is all white because I had to remove the information from it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The header for the file I have is actually [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70] which is of course not a valid PNG file header.

No, it is a JPEG header instead (the link you provided is for a file named `testimage.jpg`).  Which explains why `TPNGImage` fails.

Use [`Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage) instead.  Or better, use [`Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TWICImage) and let it work out the image type for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to TWICImage I'll have a look at that and see how it goes